# Updater crashed while "waiting for configuration file prompt"

Tags: update-manager

Updater asked about a configuration file change. I clicked to see the differences, but that operation crashed. Now I am left half-way through an update, with a box saying **waiting for configuration file prompt** and no way to give it the reply it is waiting for.

What do I do now? If I kill the Updater, will I end with a broken system (half updated)?
Help please.

Answer (score 1):

I found success by forcibly rebooting the host via `sudo reboot` and then resolving the incomplete upgrade by opening a terminal and running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`